# Angular / Firestore - Display placeholder or loader until data is fetched

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I have Firestore query that fetches a bunch of images from a collection. In one of my components I have a button that allows images to be uploaded. When I select an image to be uploaded, I would like to display the mat progress bar until I've populated a firestore node with the storage URL.

The issue I seem to be having is that because it's not just one image I'm viewing, it's multiple, I can't seem to work out how to toggle the mat progress bar on or off without affecting all the other images and not just the new image.

What's happening is that when I select an image, nothing displays until the node has been populated and the image is read (image.newImageURL). During this time, I would like to display my loader.

It's worth noting that I might end up individually uploading 5 images, so the loader will need to display inside the container of the new awaiting image and not on the others as indicated by it's position in the html.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

**My HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="imageUL" [sortablejs]="itemsArr" [sortablejsOptions]="options">
    <li class="image" *ngFor="let image of images | async; let i = index" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + (image.newImageURL | async)  + ')'}">
      <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="!image.newImageURL" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Getting the image data**

```
  getImages() {

this.imagesCollection = this.afs.collection<any>(`${this.issueId}/images`, ref => {
  return ref.orderBy('image_order');
});

this.images = this.imagesCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {


  // Empty the itemsArr so that we have a clean slate to add the updates in
  this.itemsArr = [];

  return actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;

    console.log('data = ' + data);

    // Firebase Reference
    var storage = firebase.storage();

    if (data.image_photo_thumbnail != undefined) {

      // Get the image storage reference
      var image = data.image_photo_thumbnail;

      //Create an image reference to the storage location
      var imagePathReference = storage.ref().child(image);

      // Get the download URL and set the local variable to the result (url)
      var newImageURL = Observable.from(imagePathReference.getDownloadURL());

    }

    this.itemsArr.push({ id, ...data });

    return { id, newImageURL, ...data };

  });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the following HTML outside of the list item so it always appears after the list of images.

```
<li class="image" *ngIf="showImageLoading">
 <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
</li>
```